# Binary tree only printing first value with in-order traversal

Tags: c, binary-tree

I created a binary tree program and I wanted to do in-order traversal to display the values and then eventually compare it to another tree, but the in-order traversal is only printing the first value.

Why is this happening? I thought it might be the way I am creating the tree but I wouldn't know for sure. Maybe I need to have my values in an array first?

```c
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct treenode {
    int data;
    struct treenode *left;
    struct treenode *right;
} node;

struct treenode *tree;

void inorderTraversal(struct treenode *);
void create_tree(struct treenode *);
struct treenode *insertElement(struct treenode *, int);

void create_tree(struct treenode *tree) { tree = NULL; }

struct treenode *insertElement(struct treenode *tree, int val) {
    struct treenode *ptr, *nodeptr, *parentptr;
    ptr = (struct treenode *)malloc(sizeof(struct treenode));
    ptr->data = val;
    ptr->left = NULL;
    ptr->right = NULL;
    if (tree == NULL) {
        tree = ptr;
        tree->left = NULL;
        tree->right = NULL;
    } else {
        parentptr = NULL;
        nodeptr = tree;
        while (nodeptr != NULL) {
            parentptr = nodeptr;
            if (val < nodeptr->data)
                nodeptr = nodeptr->left;
            else
                nodeptr = nodeptr->right;
        }
        if (val < parentptr->data)
            parentptr->left = ptr;
        else
            parentptr->right = ptr;
    }
    return tree;
}

void inorderTraversal(struct treenode *tree) {
    if (tree != NULL) {
        inorderTraversal(tree->left);
        printf("%d\t", tree->data);
        inorderTraversal(tree->right);
    }
}
int main(void) {
    int val;
    struct treenode *ptr;
    create_tree(tree);

    printf("\n Enter the value of the new node : ");
    scanf("%d", &val);
    tree = insertElement(tree, val);

    printf("The Tree in order traversal\n");
    inorderTraversal(tree);
}
```

Comment: You only insert one node into the tree. What did you expect?

Comment: Aside: the poor formatting makes the code very hard to read. There's no real excuse for this with a decent editor.

Comment: While it's not a problem in this code, yet, passing around the address of a global variable and using the same name as a parameter will likely lead to problems eventually. Make it a practise to NOT use global variables.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code and also noted that the program, as is, only allows for the entry and creation of one tree structure as also noted in the good comments above.  Also, I noticed that the compiler warned of the fact that variable pointer "*ptr" in the main function was not being used, which was another clue as to a need for some refactoring.

Determining that some type of continual entry of multiple values (and the creation of subsequent tree structures) needed to be added, I performed the following code refactoring.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct treenode
{
    int data;
    struct treenode *left;
    struct treenode *right;
} node;

void inorderTraversal(struct treenode *);
void create_tree(struct treenode *);
struct treenode * insertElement(struct treenode *, int);

int main(void)
{
    int val = 1;
    struct treenode *ptr;
    ptr = NULL;
    //create_tree(tree);        /* Function was not needed since ptr is being used as the reference pointer */

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter the value of the new node or \"-999\" to end : ");
        scanf("%d", &val);
        if (val == -999)        /* An arbitrary value to cease data entry */
        {
            break;
        }
        ptr = insertElement(ptr, val);
    }

    printf("The Tree in order traversal\n");
    inorderTraversal(ptr);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

struct treenode * insertElement(struct treenode *tree, int val)
{
    struct treenode *ptr, *nodeptr, *parentptr;
    ptr = (struct treenode*)malloc(sizeof(struct treenode));
    ptr->data = val;
    ptr->left = NULL;
    ptr->right = NULL;
    if(tree == NULL)        /* True upon the initial call to this function */
    {
        tree = ptr;
        tree->left = NULL;
        tree->right = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        parentptr = NULL;
        nodeptr = tree;
        while(nodeptr != NULL)
        {
            parentptr = nodeptr;
            if(val < nodeptr->data)
                nodeptr = nodeptr->left;
            else
                nodeptr = nodeptr->right;
        }
        if(val<parentptr->data)
            parentptr->left = ptr;
        else
            parentptr->right = ptr;
    }
    return tree;        /* This will be the initial level tree pointer */
}

void inorderTraversal(struct treenode *tree)
{
    if(tree != NULL)
    {
        inorderTraversal(tree->left);
        printf("Tree data: %d\n", tree->data);
        inorderTraversal(tree->right);
    }
}
```

Following are some of the highlights.

- Since you defined function prototypes straight away, the main function was moved up so as to quickly display the top-level functionality of the program - not necessary, but beneficial.
- Noting that the variable pointer "*ptr" should be the key element in creating tree structures, that variable is utilized in the main function in lieu of the tree pointer variable.
- Once the "*ptr" variable was tagged for storage and reference of the tree structure, and upon inspection of how the "tree" variable was being utilized in the various functions, it became clear that the global tree variable and the associated "create_tree" function was not needed and so was removed.
- Within the main function, a "while" loop was added to allow for more than one tree value to be entered - an arbitrary input value of "-999" was used as a flag to end data entry.
- Some cosmetic changes to the print functions were made to produce standard output at the terminal.

With those refactored bits, following is sample run of the program with multiple inputs entered in a random fashion.

```
@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/NewTree/bin/Release$ ./NewTree 
Enter the value of the new node or "-999" to end : 33
Enter the value of the new node or "-999" to end : 89
Enter the value of the new node or "-999" to end : -22
Enter the value of the new node or "-999" to end : 13244
Enter the value of the new node or "-999" to end : -345
Enter the value of the new node or "-999" to end : 867
Enter the value of the new node or "-999" to end : 0 
Enter the value of the new node or "-999" to end : 111
Enter the value of the new node or "-999" to end : -999
The Tree in order traversal
Tree data: -345
Tree data: -22
Tree data: 0
Tree data: 33
Tree data: 89
Tree data: 111
Tree data: 867
Tree data: 13244
```

Give these refactored bits a try and see if it meets the spirit of your project.

As noted, an arbitrary value of "-999" was used in the refactored code; however, one might consider allowing the entry of string data and then using the "atoi" function to convert actual numeric values to integers, allowing for some type of string entry such as "end" to note the completion of data entry.